# Is it possible to call Windows API function to Read/Write INI file directly?

Tags: windows, external-calls

I want to create a function to read or wirte windows `*.ini` files, so I plant to call `GetPrivateProfileString` and `WritePrivateProfileString` ,refering to codes in C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

```
AppendTo[$LibraryPath, "c:\\windows\\system32"];

FindLibrary["kernel32.dll"];(*Ok*)

fun = LibraryFunctionLoad["kernel32.dll", 
  "GetPrivateProfileString", {String, String, String, String, Integer,
    String}, String]
```

it returns `$Failed` and error message

```
LibraryFunction::libload: The function GetPrivateProfileString was not loaded from the file C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll.
```

Whether is it necessary to do this with other functions or codes of `LibaryLink`? any other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`LibraryFunctionLoad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html) is not for loading arbitrary functions. It is for loading functions specifically written to extend Mathematica. It cannot be used this way.

---

For using the Windows API, look at [Calling DLLs from the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromTheWolframLanguage.html#32076), which has multiple examples of precisely this.

Answer (score 5):

```
(* .NET C# dll declaration:

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern long WritePrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Value, string FilePath);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string Section, string Key, string Default, StringBuilder RetVal, int Size, string FilePath);
*)


Needs["NETLink`"];

fSetINI = 
  DefineDLLFunction["WritePrivateProfileString", "kernel32.dll", 
   "long", {"string", "string", "string", "string"}];
path = "c:\\test.INI";(*created automaticly if not exits*)
fSetINI["System", "Path", "C:\\Windows\\System32", path]

fGetINI = 
  DefineDLLFunction["GetPrivateProfileString", "kernel32.dll", 
   "void", {"string", "string", "string", "System.Text.StringBuilder",
     "int", "string"}, MarshalStringsAs -> "Unicode"];
path = "c:\\test.INI";
sb = NETNew["System.Text.StringBuilder"];
fGetINI["System", "Path", "", sb, 255, path]
sb@ToString[]
```

Imperfect that it depends on `NETLink`.